# Add Database Row Button Cakephp

Tags: forms, cakephp, controller, cakephp-1.3

The Controller:

```
function add(){
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $qnote = $this->Qnote->save($this->data);
        if (!empty($qnote)) {
            $this->data['Step']['qnote_id'] = $this->Qnote->id;
            $this->Qnote->Step->save($this->data);
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash('Your note has been saved.');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

The Form.

```
<?php
$userID = Authsome::get('id');
echo $form->create('Qnote', array('action'=>'add'));
echo $form->input('Qnote.id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
echo $form->input('Qnote.user_id', array('value' => $userID, 'type' => 'hidden'));
echo $form->input('Qnote.subject');
echo $form->input('Qnote.body', array('rows' => '3'));
echo $form->input('Step.id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
echo $form->input('Step.user_id', array('value' => $userID, 'type' => 'hidden'));
echo $form->input('Step.body', array('rows' => '3'));
echo $form->end('Save Notes');
?>
```

This Form Adds Data in 2 Models. 
    Model 1 = Qnote;
    Model 2 = Step;
I am able to add Data to the Models.

I was wondering I could add a button to the form 
The Button would allow users to add multiple Step.data to the Step model. 
Some like a +1 Button.

Basically I want to add multiple steps Per Qnote.

Could someone point me in the right direction how i can achieve this.

Comment: Have a look at the saveAll method : http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data You'll need to format your data though

Answer (score 0):

This is something I would do with jQuery. Basically all you need to do is using jQuery to dynamically add more inputs in the CakePHPs conventions: `Step.0.user_id` for example.
What you need to do now on a +1: you need to count the zero up, so you will get `Step.1.user_id` and so on.

**First option: Use a jQuery-Script for doing this**

```
var count = 1;
$('#add_step').click(function() {
    var new_form = $('.Step').eq(0).clone();

    $('input, textarea, select, radio', new_form).filter('[name^="data"]').each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        var new_name = name.replace(/\[\d*\]/, '['+count+']');
        $(this).attr('name', new_name).attr('value', '');
    });
    $('#YourForm').after(new_form);
    count+;
    return false;
});
```

In this case you're cloning a div with the class `step` which holds your inputs for the model `Step`. You then replace the name-attribute to replace the zeros through the new value of the variable `count`. `count++` enables you to add as many steps as you want.

This is an jQuery only solution and may require additional work for your environment.

**Second option: Use AJAX with an element**

You could also write a function in your `StepsController` which renders an element which holds your form and takes care of the counter.

**Third option: Use a URL-parameter to decide how many options you want**

If you have an URL like `/qnote/add/3` you could use the 3 as a parameter in a for-loop to iterate through these form-inputs.
You need to take care, that eventually already typed in values are sent with the form when adding another Step so that these don't get lost.

Hope this helps to get on the right way.